# Trying to return a variable to use in another function, but unable to do so

Tags: python, global

I need to use a variable defined inside a particular function in another function.  Normally I would use return, but it doesn't seem to be working here.  Is this an instance in which I should use a global variable?  It doesn't seem to work because the variable I want to return is in an if statement within the try statement.

In this function I am opening a line file containing a series of passwords separated by line.  I need to return a password to be used to log in to a remote host.

```
def password():
    try:
        words =  open('words', 'r')
        for i, line in enumerate(words):
            if i == 999:
                otpw = line.replace('999','')[1:]
                return otpw
    except IOError:
        print "error opening otpw document.  Contact"
        words.close()
    finally:
        words.close()

password()
```

thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? `return otpw` will return the 1000th line of the file with all occurrences of `999` deleted and the first character removed. Your call `password()` doesn't use the returned value.

Comment: This is because in case of an exception your function terminates before returning anything.

Comment: @Tomarinator: If there is an exception then there is nothing to return

Comment: @Borodin OP seems to be confusing this problem with a problem of scope resolution of local and global variables, and seems to be confused regarding not being able to use the 'supposed to be returned' variable in the case where it is never returned.

Comment: Hi Borodin, exactly so.  That's what I want.  It does exactly this as long as I call that otpw inside the password() function.  If I try to use otpw anywhere else it says otpw is not defined.  If I set otpw outside of the function first, like putting a otpw = None, it just returns none even after I run password().  thanks!

Comment: @Tomarinator That could be.  It does return something though.  If I do a print otpw inside of that if statement, it does print the password at line 1000 as expected.  If I use return otpw and try to print the password outside the function, it indicates not defined.  Any guidance on this would be great.  Especially if I am not understanding.

Comment: @Kuldan: I think some time reviewing Python names would help. `otpw` will only be define 1) Inside the scope of `password` 2) and only if the line defining it is executed. You should return the value of `otpw` into another variable outside of `password` Something like `otpw=password()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
If you want the program to fail on exception you can just open the file using with statement. It will take care of closing the file even on an exception. This is usually the preferable method.

```
def password():
    otpw = None
    with open('words', 'r') as words:
        #Do whatever to get your password 
        for i, line in enumerate(words):
            if i == 999:
                otpw = line.replace('999','')[1:]
                return otpw
```

Now when you call password() it will either return the password or fail with an exception.

**Option 2:**
If you do want to handle exceptions on your own, set otpw to None initially and return it in your finally.

```
def password():
otpw = None
    try:
        words =  open('words', 'r')
        for i, line in enumerate(words):
            if i == 999:
                otpw = line.replace('999','')[1:]
                break
    except IOError:
        print "error opening otpw document.  Contact"
        words.close()
    finally:
        words.close()
        return otpw
```

when you call password() check for the return value. If it is None you know you have an error, else do something with the pwd. I am just calling it, otpw based on your comments, to match with anycode that may be using that name

```
otpw = password()
if otpw == None:
    print "Error retrieving password"
else:
    #do something with pwd
```

Comment: thanks for looking at this, I tried setting otpw to none (otpw=None) but I run in to a similar error.  Now if I try to use otpw outside of the function, it just returns none.  It doesn't contain the password at line 1000

Comment: You cannot use otpw outside the function. The scope of otpw is limited to password function. If you need it outside you have to set it  as 'otpw=password()' and then use it. This otpw will have nothing to do with the one in the passsword function, so it as good as any other variable like x=password()

Comment: Also, if you prefer to use otpw as a global variable you have it set it to something like 'None' outside the function and then inside password function declare it as global with 'global otpw'. This will make sure it will modify the global otpw.

Comment: That did it, thank you!  otpw=password().... I am just starting out and didn't know this was the way to do that!

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect this. Please select it as an answer if you think it answered your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def password():
try:
    optw = 'exception'
    words =  open('words', 'r')
    for i, line in enumerate(words):
        if i == 999:
            otpw = line.replace('999','')[1:]
            return otpw
except IOError:
    print "error opening otpw document.  Contact"
    words.close()
finally:
    return optw
    words.close()

password()
```

I have added a little modification to the code, now if you run it, it will always return something. If exception is reached it will just return the string 'exception'.